# Filtering system files recursively with QT 5.10

Tags: c++, qt

I’m using a QFileSystemModel and hopping to filter system files recursively using a QSortFilterProxyModel. The root folder does work quite well but none of the files within the folders are shown in the result.

EDIT (full example):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTreeView>
#include <QFileSystemModel>

int main(int in_argc, char **in_argv)
{
    QString l_path = "C:/";

    QApplication l_app(in_argc, in_argv);
    QMainWindow l_window;

    QFileSystemModel l_model;
    l_model.setFilter(QDir::AllEntries);
    QModelIndex l_index = l_model.setRootPath(l_path);

    QSortFilterProxyModel l_filter;
    l_filter.setSourceModel(&l_model);
    l_filter.setRecursiveFilteringEnabled(true);

    QListView *l_view = new QListView;
    l_view->setModel(&l_filter);
    l_view->setRootIndex(l_filter.mapFromSource(l_index));

    QWidget l_widget;
    QVBoxLayout l_layout;
    QLineEdit l_line;
    l_layout.addWidget(&l_line);
    l_layout.addWidget(l_view);
    l_widget.setLayout(&l_layout);

    l_window.connect(&l_line, &QLineEdit::textChanged, [&l_filter](const QString &in_text)
    {
        l_filter.setFilterWildcard(in_text);
    });
    l_window.setCentralWidget(&l_widget);
    l_window.show();

    return l_app.exec();
}
```

I haven’t seen any example as a proof of concept so I’m wondering if setRecursiveFilteringEnabled is supposed to work with a QFileSystemModel or maybe I'm missing something?